# How to get patches for Java SE?

Tags: java, patch-management

I have been struggling with this all day. Going on day 2.

I created a support.oracle.com account and can login, however I am redirected a page asking for a Support Identifier. I do not have one, reading it says it would have sent with the registration email, it was not.

See attached email

[image]

I called customer support, they asked me what product I was trying to patch, "Java SE"

Specifically "Oracle Java SE 1.7.0_301 / 1.8.0_291 / 1.11.0_11 / 1.16.0_1 Multiple Vulnerabilities (Apr 2021 CPU)" from the nessus scans.

They asked me who paid for the license, "There is there a license?"  I called sales, they said I would need to get in contact with my org administrator to get the CSI, that is me, I just setup the account yesterday.

Am I doing something wrong? How to get patches for Java SE?

Answer (score 1):

Without any cost, you will not get any updates from Oracle.
You need a license for Oracle SE, if you got that, you get your CSI.

If your organization has a license, you need to ask the department responsible for this license to get it.

If you don’t have any license, you should not use Oracle SE but switch to a OpenJDK distribution like Adoptium.